# One div seems to be swallowed up by another

Tags: html, css, firebug, styling

I have this page:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/birds/birds.php

The left side (on the middle) has a list of birds.  But for some reason, the web page renders only half of the bird list.  If I do view-source, I see the entire bird list.

If I look at the page in Firebug, it shows the spacing of the divs as I expected it, but for some reason, just the top part of the list of birds doesn't appear.

Any idea why that is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I can see all of them. What browser version are you using?

Comment: @Ovidiu I am using Chrome.  What are the first bird species you see?

Comment: Take a look at @Commissioner Gordon's answer. It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a quote at the end of your style declaration for parent div.

```
<div bird.php?bird_id="10501"" birds="" outdoors="" www.comehike.com="" http:="" style="width: 275px; float: left;>
```

needs to be

```
<div bird.php?bird_id="10501" birds="" outdoors="" www.comehike.com="" http:="" style="width: 275px; float: left;">
```

Comment: Good find!! Will accept your answer in 7 min when this site allows me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When I take a quick look with Chrome, I think it renders the whole list, but breaks the layout.

It might help clearing the float, by adding `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` just before you close mainBody.

edit: fixed a typo